# Solution of this easy trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a problem with my trigger(Im new with oracle)
With this trigger I want when insert a new contract and this contracts have a start_date which is before that end_date  of the other contract of this user, the trigger have to change the old end_date to the start_date of the new contract.

Here is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Date_contracts
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF START_DATE ON CONTRACTS
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
      IF :NEW.START_DATE < (SELECT DISTINCT END_DATE FROM CONTRACTS WHERE SSN = NEW.SSN) 
      THEN OLD.END_DATE := NEW.START_DATE;
      END IF;
    END;
    /
```

And sql developres says that subquery not allowed in this context. Im sure that is to repair but I cant solve it because my level is so low. I hope you help me:) Thanks

Comment: It is a warning that shows **It might return more than 1 record**

Comment: You have a fundamental misunderstanding of triggers if you think you can change the old start date.

Answer (score 0):

1.

SELECT DISTINCT END_DATE FROM CONTRACTS WHERE SSN = NEW.SSN
May Return one or more record which may cause proble.

2.

selecting from same table within trigger on which trigger is created may cause problem.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, this was the problem :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

reed about [Using Triggers](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg13trg.htm)
You cant set :OLD. values - this is read only value (:old values is values of updated row before update)...
probably you try do this

```
update CONTRACTS set END_DATE = :NEW.START_DATE 
where SSN = :NEW.SSN and END_DATE < :NEW.START_DATE and someid <> nvl(:OLD.someid, :NEW.someid)
```